# Разбивка Json с помощью json_populate_recordset

Tags: json, postgresql, postgresql9.5

Таблица содержит данные типа json.
Необходимо вытащить эти данные и привести в читаемый вид.

Данные:
[image: данные]

Вытаскиваю их запросом:

```
select distinct
json_each_text(value)
from
(
select
(json_each(jsondata::json)).*
from
mv_custom_form
where
jsondata <> '{}'
) T
;
```

Результат: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Целесообразно ли это, если после этого я хочу получить данные в виде
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

используя json_populate_record

```
select distinct * from 
json_populate_recordset(
null :: text,
(
    select distinct json_each_text(value) from (select (json_each(jsondata::json)).* from mv_custom_form
    where jsondata <> '{}') T
 )
)
;
```

результат:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По ошибке понятно, что неверно указан тип данных, но какой указать и как правильней задать пока не доходит.
Прошу помочь =)
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Какой именно вид вы считаете читаемым? То есть что должно быть в результате?

Comment: @Мелкий в результате хочется получить таблицу с значениями. 
 Шапка таблицы, вида: |group001|group002||group003|group004|...

Comment: выводить значения с помощью jsondata ->'group001' ->>'reason' проблематично, тк таблица будет иметь пустые столбцы и строки, да и данных в рабочей БД очень много.